# group by a topic and collapse a column of strings into respective categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Given:

```
import pandas as pd

lis1= ('baseball', 'basketball', 'baseball', 'hockey', 'hockey', 'basketball')
lis2= ('I had lots of fun', 'This was the most boring sport', "I hit the ball hard", 'the puck went too fast', 'I scored a goal', 'the basket was broken')

pd.DataFrame({'topic':lis1, 'review':lis2})

        topic                          review
0    baseball               I had lots of fun
1  basketball  This was the most boring sport
2    baseball             I hit the ball hard
3      hockey          the puck went too fast
4      hockey                 I scored a goal
5  basketball           the basket was broken
```

I need this as a pd.DataFrame:

```
lis1= ('baseball', 'basketball', 'hockey')
lis2= ("I had lots of fun, I hit the ball hard", "This was the most boring sport, the basket was broken","the puck went too fast I scored a goal")

pd.DataFrame({'topic':lis1, 'review':lis2})

        topic                                             review
0    baseball             I had lots of fun, I hit the ball hard
1  basketball  This was the most boring sport, the basket was...
2      hockey             the puck went too fast I scored a goal
```

I'm confused because the column I'd like to group by is a string and I'd like to combine the strings together. The strings do not have to be divided by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and aggregate the strings via `str.join`:

```
df.groupby('topic', as_index=False).agg({'review' : ', '.join})

        topic                                             review
0    baseball             I had lots of fun, I hit the ball hard
1  basketball  This was the most boring sport, the basket was...
2      hockey            the puck went too fast, I scored a goal
```

Or, `groupby` and call `apply`, with a slightly different syntax:

```
df.groupby('topic')['review'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()

        topic                                             review
0    baseball             I had lots of fun, I hit the ball hard
1  basketball  This was the most boring sport, the basket was...
2      hockey            the puck went too fast, I scored a goal
```